# Reading database records in batches and sorting it

Tags: java, mysql, file-writing

I have a database with multiple tables containing millions of records (~100K million records).My goal is to process the data(some basic BODMAS operations) and then write it into a CSV file in batches. To optimize memory, I want to write it in batches of 100K at a time into the file.
But I want to have these records sorted when I write it into the file. Is there a way to do it?
Application code is in java.

Comment: When you say "But I want to have these records sorted when I write it into the file." Does that mean you want to sort the records just before you write them to the file after the database read, or can they be sorted in the database?

Answer (score 0):

I see no need to break into batches *for this query*.

I suspect (without concrete proof) that MySQL can handle

```
 SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE '...'
     FROM ...
     ORDER BY ...
```

The `INTO OUTFILE` is probably just a continual operation.  Breaking it into chunks would only make it take longer overall.

`ORDER BY` would require an on-disk sort (unless you are ordering by the `PRIMARY KEY`).  Although that is costly, any size (even 100M rows) is feasible, given enough disk space.

Furthermore, if you would be combining the CSV files and sorting them, that would very likely take even more time.  So do it all at once.